# Assign a unique color to each distinct value in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

How can a data frame like the below, but one whose values are unknown before runtime, be rendered with a unique color assigned to each distinct value? For example, in the below case, a valid solution would be to color cell `A0` green, `A1` red, `B0` red, `B1` blue, `C0` yellow and `C1` purple. `A1` and `B0` must have the same color, because they have the same value. All other cells must have unique colors, because they hold unique values.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"A": ["Alice", "Bob"], "B": ["Bob", "John"], "C": [123, 456]})
```

```
       A     B    C
0  Alice   Bob  123
1    Bob  John  456
```

Comment: In this case you will need to formulate, a map and build up the conditons for each cell

Comment: You may want to check this guide to conditional formatting in pandas: https://towardsdatascience.com/a-quick-and-easy-guide-to-conditional-formatting-in-pandas-8783035071ee

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`seaborne.color_palette`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html) as a convenience to generate colors (alternatively any other method that gives you `n` unique colors), and [`factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) to map the unique values:

```
import seaborn as sns

def color_unique(df):
    # get unique values
    a, unique = pd.factorize(df.stack())

    # generate a color palette with as many colors
    # as there are unique values
    palette = sns.color_palette(None, len(unique)).as_hex()

    return (pd.DataFrame(a.reshape(df.shape),
                         index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
              .replace(dict(enumerate(palette)))
              .radd('background-color: ')
            )

df.style.apply(color_unique, axis=None)
```

Output:

[image: pandas style cell unique color per value]

Output of `color_unique(df)`:

```
                           A                          B                          C
0  background-color: #1f77b4  background-color: #ff7f0e  background-color: #2ca02c
1  background-color: #ff7f0e  background-color: #d62728  background-color: #9467bd
```